# Cakephp 2.0 using xml in plugin

Tags: php, xml, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to migrate the plugin from cakephp 1.3 to 2.x.

**Original code**

```
        App::import('Core', 'Xml');
        $Xml = new Xml($response);
        $response = $Xml->toArray(false); // Send false to get separate elements
        $Xml->__destruct();
        $Xml = null;
```

I think in cakephp 2.x **app::import('Core', 'Xml');** world become **App::import('Utility', 'Xml');** Should i use **Xml::toArray(Xml::build($response));**. Then I am stuck. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it would become

```
App::uses('Xml', 'Utility');
```

as App::import() is now only for non-class files and vendor files.

Then you can use it just like this:

```
$xml = Xml::build($filenameOrXmlContent);
$array = Xml::toArray($xml);
```

see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/xml.html

Comment: Thanks mark for your help. One last thing will App::import('Core', 'http_socket'); become App::uses('HttpSocket', 'Utility'); right??

Comment: Yep, the first one is the class, the second one the package/namespace.